# Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff font missing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, playframework, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using uib-datepicker-popup component ( UI Bootstrap). And it seams that glyphicons fonts are missing. I'm using webjars for loading dependencies.
Folder assets font is missing definitely, component is missing next or previous simbol

[image: ![next or previous is missing]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAE3y.png)

I used standard import in build.sbt ( "org.webjars" % "angular-ui-bootstrap" % "2.2.0")

This is my build.sbt:

```
// Dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  filters,
  evolutions,
  jdbc,
  cache,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.5.0",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.0" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0",
  specs2 % Test,
  // WebJars (i.e. client-side) dependencies
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.5.0",
  "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.14-1",
  "org.webjars" % "underscorejs" % "1.6.0-3",
  "org.webjars" %  "font-awesome"  % "4.7.0",
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "1.11.1",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.6" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
  "org.webjars" % "angularjs" % "1.4.9" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
  "org.webjars" % "angular-ui-bootstrap" % "2.2.0"
)
```

This is my header

```
<!-- Favicon and Apple Icons -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("images/logo/logo_small.png")'>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("images/ico/apple-touch-icon.png")'>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png")'>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png")'>

<!-- Angular JavaScript -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("jquery.min.js"))'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("angular.min.js"))'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("angular-resource.min.js"))'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("angular-route.min.js"))'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/angular/app.js")'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/angular/services.js")'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/angular/directives.js")'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/angular/controllers.js")'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/dirPagination.js")'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/angular-file-upload-all.js")'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/angular-datepicker.js")'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.jsRoutes"></script>

<!-- Date picker dependacy JavaScripts -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("angular-animate.js"))'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("angular-sanitize.js"))'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"))'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("bootstrap.min.js"))'></script>


<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/jquery.bootstrap-growl.min.js")'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/common/main.js")'></script>
```

I get console error because fonts are missing:

```
 GET http://localhost:9000/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 

 GET http://localhost:9000/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

﻿
Being newbie i forgot something trivial i supose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submitting question i have omitted source of problem

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/angular-datepicker.css")'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("font-awesome.min.css"))'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css")'>
```

We are using bootstrap based template Bootswatch: Cerulean, it has problem with fonts so solution is to manually put missing fonts in directory

```
/public/fonts

glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```